# Como fazer controle de versão ( git, version control) usando jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, git

Comecei recentemente a programas em *Python* usando o *Jupyter Notebook* (web) e queria dar um `push` no meu repositório no GitHub.

Clonei meu repositório pelo `cmd`, alterei o documento, fiz um monte de coisa, agora ele tá salvo na minha máquina e quero subir no GitHub. Eu tenho que fechar o kernel e faço o `git push` no cmd? 
Faço isso dentro do JN mesmo?
Existe um passo a passo pra isso?

Agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Talvez a dúvida seja em como usar o git. Se não me engano o arquivo do jupyter .ipynb funciona igual outro .txt, .c, .py, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Isso - 
basicamente, o Jupyter guarda todos os dados da sessão nos arquivos do tipo `.ipynb`. Então são esses arquivos que você tem que manter versionados.

Para isso é importante sim parar o sevidor do Jupyter (não conheço os mecanismos dele muito a fundo, pode ser que  só fechar o kernel seja o suficiente) - um bom indicativo vai ser a data-e-hora da ultima modificiação do seu arquivo `.ipynb`.

Vocẽ diz que o documento já está no repositório, então suponho que já seja o .ipynb que te interessa.

Pelo terminal (`cmd` no Windows), você tem digitar dois comandos do git: primeiro  um "commit" seguido de um push:

```bsh
git commit [nome_do_arquivo].ipynb -m "[descrição curta das alterações]"
git push
```

Se estiver tudo ok, ambos os comandos vão dizer isso em sua saída.

## se o arquivo não estiver versionado

Se o arquivo `.ipynb` ainda não estiver no repositório, ele deve ser adicionado antes, com o comando `git add`:

```
git add [nome_do_arquivo].ipynb
```

Em seguida, os comandos `commit` e `push` vão funcionar como acima.

Comment: Olá jsbueno, obrigada pelas instruções mas eu devo estar fazendo algo errado. Então eu criei o arquivo .ipynb depois de clonar o repositório, ou seja ele não está originalmente no meu github. Quando eu faço os seus comandos, ele não reconhece o arquivo para comitar, justamente porque ele ainda não existe no meu ambiente. Dado que eu precisei desligar o computador, agora eu só tenho o repositório atualizado na minha máquina. Se eu clonar o repositório novamente, eu vou sobreescrever, certo? Como eu referencio que aquele é o repositório que eu quero atualizar?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta para esse caso.

Comment: Mas como ele vai saber de qual repositório eu to falando?

Comment: você disse que ja tinha acertado a parte do repositório - se o arquivo está numa pasta que veio do repositorio do github, essa pasta tem uma outra pasta de nome ".git", que tem as informações de verrsionamento e de repositórios remotos.